# how to find wildcard in winword "word search is too complex"

Tags: regex, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, wildcard

I would like to find few sentence with "word space" and "non-breaking space" both condition in single pattern in winword by wildcard.

if i use below pattern, i got error "word search is too complex" because of the range would allow < 7 only. Then, how to find below text?

```
Reciprocal[\s ]Enforcement[\s ]of[\s ]Commonwealth[\s ]Judgments[\s ]Act[\s ]\(Cap[\s ][0-9]{1,3},[\s ]s[\s ][0-9]{1,3}\([0-9]{1,3}\)\([a-z]{1,1}\)\)\.
```

Below my sample text:

```
Reciprocal Enforcement of Commonwealth Judgments Act (Cap 233, s 23(1)(a)).
Reciprocal Enforcement of Commonwealth Judgments Act (Cap 143, s 87(2)(x)).
Reciprocal Enforcement of Commonwealth Judgments Act (Cap 283, s 64(3)(y)).
Reciprocal Enforcement of Commonwealth Judgments Act (Cap 233, s 52(4)(d)).
```

Remark: Word space would be either "non breaking space" or "word space".

Please help me to solve this!

I will be appreciate, if some one give quick solution.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,

Saran

Comment: I see your pattern, but where's the sample data your trying to match??

Comment: Hi Expert, thanks for quick review, i have added my sample text